# Inline block not giving desired effect

Tags: angular, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to build a very basic store page. One of the products i would like to appear like this:

[image]

But unfortunately it is appearing like this:

[image]

I'm trying to use inline block to have the negotiate button and product price on the same line, with the button dragged to the left and the priced dragged to the right, but inline block doesnt seem to be working correctly. Can anyone tell me why?

```css
#popularSection {
  background-color: blue;
}

#product {
  outline: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 15px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#negButton {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#inline {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  width: 190px;
  height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="popularSection">
    <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">
      <div id="product">
        <img class="img-responsive" src={{path}}/>
        <p>{{productName}}</p>
        <div id="inline">
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" id="negButton" (click)="negotiate()">Negotiate</button>
          <p>{{price}}</p>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" id="addCart" (click)="addCart()">Add To Cart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex;` with `flex-direction: row;` for the container.

```css
#popularSection {
  background-color: blue;
}

#product {
  outline: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 15px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#negButton {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#inline {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

img {
  width: 190px;
  height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="popularSection">
    <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">
      <div id="product">
        <img class="img-responsive" src={{path}}/>
        <p>{{productName}}</p>
        <div id="inline">
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" id="negButton" (click)="negotiate()">Negotiate</button>
          <span>{{price}}</span>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" id="addCart" (click)="addCart()">Add To Cart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `p` tag for your price (which is a `block` element)`, consider using a`span`instead (which is an`inline` element)

You can then remove the style from your `#inline` div

*(Please note that in the snippet below, I've replaced the `{{interpolation}}` so that you can view the example without Angular)*

```css
#popularSection {
  background-color: blue;
}

#product {
  outline: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 15px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#negButton {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#inline {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  width: 190px;
  height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="popularSection">
    <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">
      <div id="product">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://craft.com.au/images/products/FPA13.jpg" />
        <p>Product 1</p>
        <div>
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" id="negButton" (click)="negotiate()">Negotiate</button>
          <span >100</span>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" id="addCart" (click)="addCart()">Add To Cart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving `display: inline-block` to the parent element. I think you must give it to the child element.

So remove `display: inline-block` from `#inline` element and give it to `#negButton` and the `p` element